# How to centerize a UICollectionView cell after it has been loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

My code below to centerize it:-

```
- (void)centerUpNext:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
    //[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self.collectionView2 scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                                    atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
}
```

This is how I assign indexPath value:-

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
        {
            NSLog(@"reminderTime is later than systemTime");
            self.upNextIndexPath = indexPath;
        }
```

And I'll call it from viewWillAppear

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
[self centerUpNext:self.upNextIndexPath];
```

This is not working as intended. As I am unable to centerize the exact cell after the collectionview is loaded. Where and when should I call this method `[self centerUpNext:self.upNextIndexPath];` ?

Comment: First, are you getting the `indexPath` that you *want* to get? If, in `viewWillAppear` you do `print(self.upNextIndexPath)` does it show the correct cell that you want to be centered?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `KVO` is the best solution.

In `viewDidLoad`, you can add

```
[self.collectionView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:"contentSize"];
```

And then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqual: @"contentSize"]) {
        if ([change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGSizeValue].height != 0 && [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] CGSizeValue].width != 0) {
        [self centerUpNext:self.upNextIndexPath];
    }
}
```

}